# How to use bodymovin / Lottie on Linux

Tags: homebrew, after-effects, lottie

AirBnB has published an *open source* tool to easily export After Effects animations to a JSON file which can then be used to publish the animation on the web or on a native mobile app. This tool is called [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web). I found the source code of the player, the sofware used to play the exported animation, but where is the source code of the animation extraction tool (previously called bodymovin? )?

I'm on Linux (Ubuntu) and I would like to be able to install a command line tool that can extract animations out of an after effect (.ae) file into a JSON file. Is it possible ?
I found this in the [official documentation](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web#option-6) :

```
Option 6:

Install with Homebrew-adobe:

brew tap danielbayley/adobe
brew cask install lottie
```

and a Linux equivalent to brew ([Linuxbrew](https://linuxbrew.sh/)). But when I run `brew cask install lottie` it says

```
Error: Installing casks is supported only on macOS
```

which, I think, means that a `cask` is an already compiled binary for macOS. Is it possible to recompile lottie from source for my platform ?

Comment: Any success? if yes, please share.

Comment: @shahzainali No success yet

Comment: Any Success mate ??

Comment: No, sorry. I had to ask the animation designer to extract the animations for the web on his Mac.

Comment: Install any virtual machine in Linux and use Aftereffect with bodymovin plugin